# how to time_bucket by month with timescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, timescaledb

As of this question, I know there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/414) to add month/year to the time_bucket function.

My question is, what is the best way to accomplish this now.  This issue mentions `date_trunc`

Here are the two approaches:

### timescaledb's time_bucket

```sql
SELECT time_bucket('1 week', timestamp) AS "one_week", 
       count(*) AS "count", 
       first(value, timestamp) AS "first", 
       last(value, timestamp) AS "last" 
FROM "event" "event" 
WHERE event."signalId" = $1 
GROUP BY one_week 
ORDER BY one_week DESC
```

### postgres date_trunc

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('month', timestamp) AS "one_month", 
       count(*) AS "count", 
       first(value, timestamp) AS "first", 
       last(value, timestamp) AS "last" 
FROM "event" "event" 
WHERE event."signalId" = $1 
GROUP BY one_month 
ORDER BY one_month DESC
```

Both of those work as expected (though I have not done any performance testing).

I would like to acheive:

- (a) gapfill (like timescaledb time_bucket_gapfill, and
- (b) last value carried forward (locf)

What is the best way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, it's sad to see that Timescale doesn't respond to requests from the community. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they are planning to support this in the future, but it has been not been included in planning for any milestones, check
https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/414

For now, I do a workaround using `time_bucket('1 day', timestamp)` or include it as part of CTE / `with`, from which I will call the on `date_trunc('month', time_bucketed_day_column)`. This way, timescaledb's gapfill function from smaller interfal (day) should be carried on the longer time interval.

Comment: there is now a survey about improving `time_bucket`: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/discussions/3258